# NSBlockOperation and NSAutoreleasePool

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoperation, nsautoreleasepool, nsblockoperation

Normally when you create an `NSOperation` subclass you are responsible for creating and releasing an `NSAutoreleasePool` in the `-main` method.

When you use an `NSBlockOperation`, do you need to create an autorelease pool in the block?

Comment: I am not aware of any documentation that says you must create an NSAutoreleasePool in your `-main` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. GCD (which NSOperationQueue is built on top of as of OS X 10.6 or iOS 4.2) manages autorelease pools for you, the same way that NSRunLoop does.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. (I recognize your name from the old REALbasic lists... boy that was a long time ago.)

Comment: Wow, blast from the past. Looks like I still have your name in my address book :)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think so, as the work queues have their own pools already created for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

Your best bet is to read up on block memory behavior with objects. Here is the link for the iOS [Blocks and Variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) the bottom of this page has information regarding object types.

Frank